javafx TreeTableColumn updateItem always called with null parameter
I have a custom TreeTableColumn class like this:
public class TaskTreeTableColumn extends TreeTableColumn<TaskBean, String>
{
    public TaskTreeTableColumn(LocalDate date)
    {
        super("" + date.getDayOfMonth());
        setCellValueFactory(cdf -> cellValueFactory(cdf, date));
        setCellFactory     (ttc -> cellFactory(ttc));
    }

    private SimpleStringProperty cellValueFactory(CellDataFeatures<TaskBean, String> cdf, LocalDate date)
    {
        return new TaskTreeTableViewCellValueFactory(date).call(cdf);
    }

    private TreeTableCell<TaskBean, String> cellFactory(TreeTableColumn<TaskBean, String> ttc)
    {
        return new TreeTableCell<>()
        {
            @Override protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b)
            {
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                super.updateItem(s, b);
            }
        };
    }
}

TaskTreeTableViewCellValueFactory implements the callback method something like this:
public class TaskTreeTableViewCellValueFactory
        implements Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TaskBean, String>, ObservableValue<String>>
{
    private final @NonNull LocalDate date;

    @Override public SimpleStringProperty call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TaskBean, String> cellDataFeatures)
    {
        return readOnlyStringWrapperFor(cellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue());
    }

    private ReadOnlyStringWrapper readOnlyStringWrapperFor(TaskBean taskBean)
    {
        return ReadOnlyStringWrapper(calculateSomeStringForTaskBasedOnDate(taskBean, date));
    }

This code works and populates my TreeTableView as expected as long as I do not add a
CellFactory like this to my column
public TaskTreeTableColumn(LocalDate date)
{
    // same as above
    setCellFactory(ttc -> cellFactory(ttc));
}

where cellFactory(ttc) is implemented like this:

    private TreeTableCell<TaskBean, String> cellFactory(TreeTableColumn<TaskBean, String> ttc)
    {
        return new TreeTableCell<>()
        {
            @Override protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b)
            {
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                super.updateItem(s, b);
            }
        };
    }

updateItem is always called with null value for s and the table cells are all blank.
Can anybody see my fault?
I have seen this post but I could not find a significant difference to what I'm trying except that I'm working on a '''TreeTableView''' instead of a '''TableView'''.

If the updateItem isn't overridden properly it'll cause your issue. My java is a bit rusty but I'd start focusing on that aspect. Are you positive the cell content is a String? I'm just guessing in the dark here

How do you know that the value is coming in null?  Have you tried explicitly handling the null case and empty and setting (or not) the Text value of the TreeTableCell?  I seem to remember that the standard TreeTableCell does this stuff, but not when you extend it.
